# Как скрыть ранее выведенные ошибки в Angular?

Tags: angularstrap, angularjs

На странице в HTML коде есть блок вывода ошибок от запроса AJAX:

```
<div class="form-error" ng-bind-html="error" ng-repeat="error in response.messages" ng-show="response.type === 'error' && !deleteSuccessInfo.hidden">

<span>{{error}}</span>
</div>
```

После каждого сабмита кнопки старые сообщения остаются на странице, как их можно убрать или скрыть спустя некоторое время?

Comment: А вы просто кладете в response то, что вам отвечает сервер? Тогда похоже, что это сервер их накапливает и каждый раз шлет вместе со старыми.

Comment: Да, я каждый раз в ответа от аякс добавляю в объект `response`

Comment: Тогда проверяйте, что вам возвращает сервер. Так как angular не сохранить предыдущий список ошибок. Он заменит его новым. Значит вам сервер присылает еще и старые ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Вы имели в виду аналог `.fadeOut`:

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <div ng-repeat="error in messages" hide="1">
            {{error}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

**js:**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
 .controller('FooController', FooController)
 .directive('hide', hide);

FooController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function FooController($scope) {
    var arr = ['foo', 'bar']; // Получили некие данные/сообщения    
    $scope.messages = arr;
}

hide.$inject = ['$timeout'];
function hide($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          delay: '=hide'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elem) {           
            $timeout(function(){
                $elem.addClass('hidden');
            }, $scope.delay * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/c76r6nzb/2/)